# java applet display image from localhost

Tags: java, image, applet

I have an image on Apache server that is oversaved 10 times in second by programm  in cpp. I would like to display on website this image that looks like animation. I wrote this script and its works in applet viewer in netbeans, but when I place class on the website, then display image and doesn't change. I spent lot of time on this and it doesn't work. Could anyone help me ?

```
public class poprawki extends Applet implements Runnable {
    Thread thread1;
    boolean running = true;
    BufferedImage obraz = null;

    public void paint(Graphics g)     {
        g.drawImage(obraz, 10, 10, null);
    }

    public void wyswietlanie_obrazu() {
        try {
            obraz =ImageIO.read(new URL("http://localhost/obraz.jpg"));
            repaint();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        setLayout(null);

        thread1 = new Thread(this);
        thread1.start();

        repaint();
    }

    public void destroy() {
        running = false;
        thread1 = null;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            try {
                wyswietlanie_obrazu();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the exception:  } catch (IOException e) {
                                  }  please handle this exception and see if any error occur when you load the image

Comment: I agree with previous answer, but would propose to use javascript on client side as this is more portable solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, as noted in the comments, don't ignore exceptions. If you didn't ignore it, you would get an error message that would explain what the problem is. Instead, by ignoring it, you put yourself in the dark.

If you run this applet on a machine which is not the apache server, then obviously it won't work. localhost is... the local host, i.e. the host where the applet runs, and not the host of the web server.

Use `Applet.getDocumentBase()` to get an URL pointing to the web server where the applet comes from.

Comment: I added new field to see  e exception and there is no error. If I use (getDocumentBase()+"obraz.jpg") then nothing display and error in new field is "javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL". Any ideas ?

Comment: Yes, print the URL, and check that it's the correct one by copy and pasting it in your browser address bar. If you don't get the image, it's not the right one.

Comment: hmmm if I print the URL (getDocumentBase() ) I get" file C://Documents......../page.html" so how to get the addres obraz.jpg with this method?

Comment: Then you have not deployed the HTML page and the applet correctly. You should not have a path to a local file in your HTML file. Edit your question and show us the code of the HTML file where you embed your applet.

Comment: I forgot to add that I have installed Apache on the Windows.                         { <HTML>
<HEAD>
   <TITLE>Applet HTML Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>


<H3><HR WIDTH="100%">Applet HTML Page<HR WIDTH="100%"></H3>

<P>
<APPLET codebase="classes" code="poprawki.class" width=350 height=200></APPLET>
</P>

<HR WIDTH="100%"><FONT SIZE=-1><I>Generated by NetBeans IDE</I></FONT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
}